# Nested Variables in Bourne Shell (bin/sh)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a variable that has a nested value.

```
x=hello
y=world
helloworld=monday

TEMP=$x$y 
echo "${!TEMP}"   # I get output "monday" which is required
```

This works in bash but not in plain sh. When I run same command using sh the last line gives "Bad Substitution".

How can I get same result using sh? For some reasons I cannot change shell from sh to bash, so I have to do this with sh.

Comment: Indirect variable name references are a major code smell. [What are you trying to do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) There's sure to be a better way.

Comment: Indeed POSIX shells don't have variable indirection and I second @johnkugelman 's comment about code smell.

Comment: I have two variables like x and y, when I combine their values they form another variable just as I mentioned above, Now I want to get value of that variable that came from value of x and y.... I dont think I am explaining it well. :(

Comment: Is there any better way to achieve the same target? coz in bash I can do that then in sh there must be a way

Comment: If you have code like this, it's a strong indication that it's time to move to another programming language.

Comment: No need for that @chepner, I figured it out.  I needed to use eval which helped me in constructing a command. that i was able to run in even bash.

Comment: Thanks @JohnKugelman and Lea for providing the concept, as I am very new to all this :D

Comment: No no, don't use eval. If you could take a step back and tell us what your larger goal is in your code, we can tell you a better way to achieve it. Read the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) page I linked in my first comment. You're asking about your attempted *solution* and we want to know what your *actual problem* is. "You are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y."

Comment: I am not very good at explaining problems, maybe this can help, I am getting issue somewhat like this. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87941/how-achieve-variable-indirection-refer-to-a-variable-whose-name-is-stored-in-an

Comment: @Rezwan You're still asking about solution Y instead of problem X. **Why** do you want indirect variable references? What is the **problem** you're trying to *solve* with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `sh` is different than `bash` [difference-between-sh-and-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash).
But you can get the content of `helloworld` using this way, maybe there is some better approach but if you're interested in just solution then this will give you what you are looking for :)

```
#!/bin/sh
x=hello
y=world
helloworld=monday
TEMP=$x$y
TEMP_FINAL='eval "echo \$$TEMP"'
eval "$TEMP_FINAL"
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I already did that and it worked, but maybe there is a better approach for that.

Comment: Yes, that's why I mentioned, but this is the tricky way with sh to do that, Good luck Rezwan.